# Should i load values from sharedpreferences in onCreate or onResume?

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, oncreate, onresume

I'm storing textview values in sharedpreferences and im not sure to load them in oncreate or in onresume?

I want to show these values again when the user closes the app and then opens it again.

StorageUtil is a class that manages my sharedpreferences.

I want to store the seekbar value in sharedpreferences.

**Seekbar value**

```
  mSeekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            StorageUtil storageUtil = new StorageUtil(getApplicationContext());
            if (mediaPlayer != null && fromUser){
                lastSeekbarPos = progress;
                mSeekbarProgress = progress * 1000;
                mediaPlayer.seekTo(mSeekbarProgress);
            }
            //Store last SeekBar position in mSharedPreferences
            storageUtil.storeSeekbarProgress(lastSeekbarPos);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        }
    });

  songList = storageUtil.getSongs();
  songIndex = storageUtil.loadSongIndex();
  lastSeekbarPos = storageUtil.loadSeekbarProgress();

  if (songList != null && !songList.isEmpty() && songIndex != -1){
        lastSeekbarPos = storageUtil.loadSeekbarProgress();

        tvSongTitle.setText(songList.get(songIndex).getTitle());
        tvArtistName.setText(songList.get(songIndex).getArtist());
        mSeekbar.setProgress(lastSeekbarPos);
        loadAlbumArt();
        loadAlbumArtBottom();
        Log.i(TAG, "Data found in mSharedPreferences");
    }else{
        mSlideUpPanel.setPanelState(SlidingUpPanelLayout.PanelState.HIDDEN);
        tvSongTitle.setText("");
        tvArtistName.setText("");
    }
```

**StorageUtil**

```
public class StorageUtil {
  private final String STORAGE = "com.vince_mp3player.STORAGE";
  private SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences;
  private Context context;
  private SharedPreferences.Editor mEditor;

public StorageUtil(Context context){
    this.context = context;
}

public void storeSeekbarProgress(int seekbarprogress) {
    mSharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(STORAGE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    mEditor = mSharedPreferences.edit();
    mEditor.putInt("seekbarProgress", seekbarprogress);
    mEditor.apply();
}

public int loadSeekbarProgress() {
    mSharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(STORAGE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return mSharedPreferences.getInt("seekbarProgress", -1);//return -1 if no data found
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either should work.

`onCreate()` is called if the Activity fully finishes, ie you close the app from Recents.

`onResume()` is also called right after `onCreate()`, as well as any time the Activity re-enters the foreground, ie going home and then opening the app from Recents.

Comment: I just tested it and my textview values are indeed stored and shown when closed and opened again, but i'm also trying to store the last position from a seekbar, but for some reason it's not loading the last position when i restart the app.

Comment: Are you saving the last position?

Comment: I edited my post, and yes i'm storing the progress from the seekbar in sharedpreferences

Comment: What is `storageUtil.storeSeekbarProgress()` doing?

Comment: I'll add it to my post, 1 sec

Comment: You should ask in a new question.

Comment: There is a count down for asking a new question, can you please help me?

Comment: I'm not allowed to. Just wait it out. You'll get more attention by asking a new question anyway.

Comment: Ok thanks anyway, i will accept your answer because i does answer my question. weird thing is that it works when i load values from shared preferences in onResume, but doesnt work in onCreate. Any idea why?